# How to Change Multi-Line string into one line string in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using the 'formula' command in Matlab to output the equation used in creating a curve fit using the fit command. The formula is outputted in a string with multiple lines. I want to use str2func to make an anonymous function of the string but the only way that can work is if the string is all in one line. I used strrep(oldstr,' ',[]) to get rid of the spaces in the string but that only eliminated the spaces within each line, keeping the string still in separate lines.

AKA my equation keeps ending up like this:
`a1*sin(b1*x+c1)+a2*sin(b2*x+c2)+a3*sin(b3*x+c3)+
a4*sin(b4*x+c4)+a5*sin(b5*x+c5)+a6*sin(b6*x+c6)+
a7*sin(b7*x+c7)+a8*sin(b8*x+c8)`

When I want it like this (It should be all in one line with no  break): `a1*sin(b1*x+c1)+a2*sin(b2*x+c2)+a3*sin(b3*x+c3)+a4*sin(b4*x+c4)+a5*sin(b5*x+c5)+a6*sin(b6*x+c6)+a7*sin(b7*x+c7)+a8*sin(b8*x+c8)`

Thanks for all the help

Comment: What is the result of calling `size` on your multiline string? Is it a cell array or a char matrix?

Comment: My multi-line string is 1 by 130 character string and my single line is a 1 by 128 character string.

Comment: So what is the value of the characters at your line breaks? Find the value, and then remove all instances of that special character.

Comment: I can solve the problem easily manually. I just manually find the indices with blank spaces and remove them. But I want to know how to automate this process and using strfind, or any kind of find function to find nulls, blanks, spaces ect turns up nothing.

Comment: have you tried to find it manually, put that line break character in its own variable and then use it for `strfind`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reshape` and then `strrep`.

```
str1 = ['a  ';'bb ';'ccc']
str2 = reshape(str1',   1,  [])   % all 1 one line after transposing the array
str3 = strrep (str2 , ' ',  '')   % remove spaces
```

Comment: EDIT: I got transpose working but it turns my entire string into one vertical line and if I try to remove spaces and re-transpose into a horizontal line it turns right back into my multi ling string..

Comment: Ok, things got even weirder. My string equation gives me 1 by 130 and using strfind for spaces gives me null values. But if I double click and open up my string equation in my variables window and use size it is suddently 1 by 8 and strfind gives me indices of 3 spaces. This is it what I want but this only happens if I manually click on the variable, otherwise it doesn't work.